# What Combine operator/approach can be used to load all pages of "paged API"?

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I am working with a web API which delivers results up to a given limit (`pageSize` parameter of the request). If the number of results surpasses this limit, the response message is pre-populated with an URL to which the follow-up request can be made to fetch more results. If there are even more results, this is again indicated in the same manner.

My intend is to fetch all results at once.

---

Currently I have something like the following request and response structures:

```swift
// Request structure
struct TvShowsSearchRequest {
    let q: String
    let pageSize: Int?
}

// Response structure
struct TvShowsSearchResponse: Decodable {
    let next: String?
    let total : Int
    let searchTerm : String
    let searchResultListShow: [SearchResult]?
}
```

When resolving the problem '**old style**' using completion handlers, I had to write a handler, which is triggering a 'handle more' request with the URL of the response:

```swift
func handleResponse(request: TvShowsSearchRequest, result: Result<TvShowsSearchResponse, Error>) -> Void {
    switch result {
    case .failure(let error):
        fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
    case .success(let value):
        print("> Total number of shows matching the query: \(value.total)")
        print("> Number of shows fetched: \(value.searchResultListShow?.count ?? 0)")

        if let moreUrl = value.next {
            print("> URL to fetch more entries \(moreUrl)")

            // start recursion here: a new request, calling the same completion handler...
            dataProvider.handleMore(request, nextUrl: moreUrl, completion: handleResponse)
        }
    }
}

let request = TvShowsSearchRequest(query: "A", pageSize: 50)
dataProvider.send(request, completion: handleResponse)
```

Internally the `send` and `handleMore` functions are both calling the same `internalSend` which is taking the `request` and the `url`, to call afterwards `URLSession.dataTask(...)`, check for HTTP errors, decode the response and call the completion block.

---

Now I want to use the Combine framework and use a Publisher which is providing the paged responses automatically, without the need to call for another Publisher.

I have therefore written a `requestPublisher` function which takes `request` and the (initial) `url` and returns a `URLSession.dataTaskPublisher` which checks for HTTP errors (using `tryMap`), `decode` the response.

Now I have to ensure that the Publisher automatically "renews" itself whenever the last emitted value had a valid `next` URL and the completion event occurs.

I've found that there is a `Publisher.append` method which would exactly do this, but the problem I had so far: I want to append only under a certain condition (=valid `next`).

The following pseudo-code illustrates it:

```swift
func requestPublisher(for request: TvShowsSearchRequest, with url: URL) -> AnyPublisher<TvShowsSearchResponse, Error> {
    // ... build urlRequest, skipped here ...

    let apiCall = self.session.dataTaskPublisher(for: urlRequest)
        .tryMap { data, response -> Data in
            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                throw APIError.server(message: "No HTTP response received")
            }
            if !(200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) {
                throw APIError.server(message: "Server respondend with status: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
            }
            return data
        }
        .decode(type: TvShowsSearchResponse.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    return apiCall
}


// Here I'm trying to use the Combine approach

var moreURL : String?

dataProvider.requestPublisher(request)
    .handleEvents(receiveOutput: {
        moreURL = $0.next   // remember the "next" to fetch more data
    })
    .append(dataProvider.requestPublisher(request, next: moreURL))  // this does not work, because moreUrl was not prepared at the time of creation!!
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { print($0) }, receiveValue: { print($0) })
    .store(in: &cancellableSet)
```

I suppose there are people out there who have already resolved this problem in a reactive way. Whenever I find a doable solution, it involves again recursion. I don't think this is how a proper solution should look like.

I'm looking for a Publisher which is sending the responses, without me providing a callback function. Probably there must be a solution using Publisher of Publishers, but I'm not yet understanding it.

---

After the comment of @kishanvekariya I've tried to build everything with multiple publishers:

1. The `mainRequest` publisher which is getting the response to the "main" request.
2. A new `urlPublisher` which is receiving all the `next` URLs of the "main" or any follow-up requests.
3. A new `moreRequest` publisher which is fetching for each value of `urlPublisher` a new request, sending all `next` URLs back to the `urlPublisher`.

Then I tried to attach the `moreRequest` publisher to the `mainRequest`  with `append`.

```swift
var urlPublisher = PassthroughSubject<String, Error>()

var moreRequest = urlPublisher
    .flatMap {
        return dataProvider.requestPublisher(request, next: $0)
            .handleEvents(receiveOutput: {
                if let moreURL = $0.next {
                    urlPublisher.send(moreURL)
                }
            })
    }

var mainRequest = dataProvider.requestPublisher(request)
    .handleEvents(receiveOutput: {
        if let moreURL = $0.next {
            urlPublisher.send(moreURL)
        }
    })
    .append(moreRequest)
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { print($0) }, receiveValue: { print($0) })
    .store(in: &cancellableSet)
```

But this still does not work... I always get the result of the "main" request. All follow up requests are missing.

Comment: you can just use another published variable where  you used moreURL, you can make this variable @published create another publisher and use sink subscriber to get update of moreURLs

Comment: @kishanvekariya I don't know if I understand correctly, but I'm now playing with a `PassthroughSubject<String, Error>` to which I'm publishing the `next` URL found in the message, then I create a `moreRequest` publisher which I then try to append it to the `mainRequest`... I will enhance the question above, as it still doesn't work. :-(

Comment: i am not sure but i think  ,      .receive(on: RunLoop.main) .  should work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that I've found the solution myself.

The idea is, that I have an `urlPublisher` which is initialized with the first URL which is then executed and may feed a `next` URL to the `urlPublisher` and by doing so causing a follow-up request.

```swift
let url = endpoint(for: request)     // initial URL
let urlPublisher = CurrentValueSubject<URL, Error>(url)

urlPublisher
    .flatMap {
        return dataProvider.requestPublisher(for: request, with: $0)
            .handleEvents(receiveOutput: {
                if let next = $0.next, let moreURL = URL(string: self.transformNextUrl(nextUrl: next)) {
                    urlPublisher.send(moreURL)
                } else {
                    urlPublisher.send(completion: .finished)
                }
            })
    }
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { print($0) }, receiveValue: { print($0) })
    .store(in: &cancellableSet)
```

So in the end, I used composition of two publishers and `flatMap` instead of the non-functional `append`. Probably this is also the solution one would target from the start...

Comment: thank you for great answer. just a couple notes: 1) `mainRequest` is `Void`, cause `.store(in:)` doesn't return a value. 2) `mainRequest` never completes. I'd add else statement with `urlPublisher.send(completion: .finished)`

Comment: @glassomoss Thanks for your comment. You are right that storing it in `mainRequest` was useless as we already have it in the `cancellableSet`. I also added the `send(completion:)` improvement in the else-case. Well spotted! This was an issue I had in the past and didn't update in my solution here.

Answer (score 1):

Before I dive into the response, just wanted to say that requesting all pages at once might not be the best idea:

1. it adds stress on the server, likely the paged API is there for a reason, to avoid costly operations on the backend
2. there is always a discussion on what to do when a page request fails: you report error, you report the partial results, you retry the request?
3. keep in mind that once you launch your product and have many clients requests for the whole data set of TV shows, the backend server might become overloaded, and generating even more failures

Now, back to the business, assuming your `requestPublisher` is properly working, what you can do is to write a publisher that chains those calls, and doesn't report values until the last page was received.

The code might look like this:

```swift
func allPages(for request: TvShowsSearchRequest, with url: URL) -> AnyPublisher<TvShowsSearchResponse, Error> {
    // helper function to chain requests for all pages
    func doRequest(with pageURL: URL, accumulator: TvShowsSearchResponse) -> AnyPublisher<TvShowsSearchResponse, Error> {
        requestPublisher(for: request, with: pageURL)
            .flatMap { (r: TvShowsSearchResponse) -> AnyPublisher<TvShowsSearchResponse, Error> in
                if let next = r.next, let nextURL = URL(string: next) {
                    // we have a `next` url, append the received page,
                    // and make the next request
                    return doRequest(with: nextURL, accumulator: accumulator.accumulating(from: r))
                } else {
                    // no more pages, we have the response already build up
                    // just report it
                    return Just(accumulator).setFailureType(to: Error.self).eraseToAnyPublisher()
                }
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    return doRequest(with: url, accumulator: TvShowsSearchResponse())
}
```

You basically use a `TvShowsSearchResponse` as an accumulator for the results of the chained request.

The above code also needs the following extension:

```swift
extension TvShowsSearchResponse {
    init() {
        self.init(next: nil, total: 0, searchTerm: "", searchResultListShow: nil)
    }
                  
    func accumulating(from other: TvShowsSearchResponse) -> TvShowsSearchResponse {
        TvShowsSearchResponse(
            next: nil,
            total: other.total,
            searchTerm: other.searchTerm,
            searchResultListShow: (searchResultListShow ?? []) + (other.searchResultListShow ?? []))
    }
}
```

, as for clarity the code that accumulates the values of `searchResultListShow` was placed into a dedicated extension.